# How to save a simple array of numbers on AppEngine (Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Does anyone knows how to save a simple array of number in an AppEngine Entity ?

For example if I have this object of class:

```
class Person {

    String name;
    Date dateOfBirth;
    int favoriteNumbers[];

    Person(String name, Date dateOfBirth, int[] favoriteNumbers) {
      this.name = name;
      this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
      this.favoriteNumbers = favoriteNumbers;
    }


  }

//save the entity ! 
     Person person = new Person("Jack", new Date(), new int[]{2, 3, 4});
     Entity entity = new Entity("person");
     entity.setProperty("name", person.name);
     entity.setProperty("dateOfBirth",person.dateOfBirth);
     entity.setProperty("favoriteNumbers",favoriteNumbers);// this here thrown an exception !




    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: firsRound: [I is not a supported property type.
        at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue(DataTypeUtils.java:235)
        at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:207)
        at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:173)
        at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:148)
        at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PropertyContainer.setProperty(PropertyContainer.java:101) 
.......
```

**Note: The code above is similar to the real. I presented this code for simplicity.  **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setProperty is expecting something that extends Collection.  As a quick fix something like the following will work:

```
Integer[] favoriteNumbers = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
entity.setProperty("favoriteNumbers", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(favoriteNumbers)));
```

However I strongly suggest that you check out a framework such as [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) which will mean you don't manually need to form the Entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `List` instead of array.